# What is the difference between a "flood" and a "flash flood"?

Tags: meteorology, weather

Whenever weather warnings come up, I have heard of both a flood watch/warning and a flash flood watch/warning.

**What is the difference between a "flood" and a "flash flood"?** Are there any specific meteorological/weather forecasting patterns that distinguish one from the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Flood:** An overflow of water onto normally dry land. The inundation of a normally dry area caused by rising water in an existing waterway,
>   such as a river, stream, or drainage ditch. Ponding of water at or
>   near the point where the rain fell. Flooding is a longer term event
>   than flash flooding: it may last days or weeks.
>
> **Flash flood:** A flood caused by heavy or excessive rainfall in a short period of time, generally less than 6 hours. Flash floods are
>   usually characterized by raging torrents after heavy rains that rip
>   through river beds, urban streets, or mountain canyons sweeping
>   everything before them. They can occur within minutes or a few hours
>   of excessive rainfall. They can also occur even if no rain has fallen,
>   for instance after a levee or dam has failed, or after a sudden
>   release of water by a debris or ice jam.
>
> *Source: [National Weather Service Weather Forecast Office](http://www.srh.noaa.gov/mrx/hydro/flooddef.php)*

Comment: In summary, a flood is a long-term event that covers normally dry areas whereas a flash flood is a short-term event that covers low-lying areas.

Comment: @edmastermind29: Main thing is that flash floods, do not last more than a few hours - unless they turn into a flood; though my experience is this normally only happens in man made drain systems, since they allow for the conference of water in much more affective ways than are naturally possible.